# Expected average distance from a random point in a square to a corner

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Given 2 randomly independently distributed variables, I would like to calculate the expected distance to the origin. This problem seems to be equivalent to calculating the average distance of all points to a corner of a square.

Comment: How are the two random variables distributed?

Comment: If this is a uniform distribution on a unit square, the answer seems to be $\frac13\left(\sqrt{2}+\log_e(\sqrt{2}+1)\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you specify the distributions of the two variables, $f_{x}(x)$ and $f_{y}(y)$, the value you're looking for is

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{x}(x)f_{y}(y) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} dx dy
$$

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are both uniform(0,1), this is

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}  dx dy \approx 0.765
$$

If you want to use a different measure of distance you can replace $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ by your preferred norm, $ \lVert (x ,y)\rVert$

Answer (score 2):

If the two random variables are IID $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ then you can
find the exact answer using the formula in @DavidLukeThiessen's Answer (+1).
Or you can approximate the answer by simulation as follows:

```
set.seed(2021)
x = runif(10^6);  y = runif(10^6)
d = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
mean(d)
[1] 0.7653568
```

The shape of the distribution of the distance is suggested by the
histogram below.

```
hist(d, prob=T, br=60, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]